# ChangeCipherSpec Authentication

Tags: tls, authentication

According to [RFC 5246](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246), 7.1. Change Cipher Spec Protocol:

> The ChangeCipherSpec message is sent during the handshake after the
> security parameters have been agreed upon, but before the verifying
> Finished message is sent.

And 6.1. Connection States:

> A TLS connection state is the operating environment of the TLS Record
> Protocol.  It specifies a compression algorithm, an encryption
> algorithm, and a MAC algorithm.... All records are
> processed under the current read and write states. The security
> parameters for the pending states can be set by the TLS Handshake
> Protocol, and the ChangeCipherSpec can selectively make either of the
> pending states current, in which case the appropriate current state is
> disposed of and replaced with the pending state; the pending state is
> then reinitialized to an empty state.  It is illegal to make a state
> that has not been initialized with security parameters a current
> state.  The initial current state always specifies that no encryption,
> compression, or MAC will be used.

ChangeCipherSpec is not covered by the Finished message. From 7.4.9. Finished:

> Note: ChangeCipherSpec messages, alerts, and any other record types
> are not handshake messages and are not included in the hash
> computations.

Forgive my ignorance, but how exactly is the ChangeCipherSpec authenticated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ChangeCipherSpec` is *not* authenticated. However, this is not a problem: its contents are unimportant (there is only one kind of `ChangeCipherSpec` message), and it may appear only at specific moments. When a client or server receives a `ChangeCipherSpec` message, it actually expects it. Thus, that message does not convey actual information; therefore, it has no need for any protection.

The main purpose of the `ChangeCipherSpec` message is to force implementations to start a new record. In SSL/TLS, handshake messages are stored in handshake records, but not with a 1-to-1 relationship: a handshake message can be split over several records, and several handshake messages can be stored into a single record. In the conceptual handshake workflow, encryption should be activated right before sending the `Finished` message; since encryption is record-based, a new record shall be opened. The `ChangeCipherSpec` message forces that new record, thus making both implementation and specification cleaner.

Comment: "...Thus, that message does not convey actual information; therefore, it has no need for any protection." - I'm not sure I agree with this (with all due respect). It violates the Horton Principal from Wagner and Schneier's [Analysis of the SSL 3.0 Protocol](https://www.schneier.com/paper-ssl.html). If a message is sent, it needs privacy or authenticity assurances. If a message does not need privacy or authenticity, then its extraneous and should be removed. However, `ChangeCipherSpec` seems to have found a home in a third state - needed but not protected.

Comment: Well, you could take the TLS spec, remove `ChangeCipherSpec`, replacing it with some words like "at this place, switch to the new algorithms and keys". It would still work. The source of the confusion is to consider `ChangeCipherSpec` as a _message_: in fact, it is more akin to, say, record headers (which are no more "protected").